# Is there a way to inherit rules from the base branch to avoid recreating rules at the child branches in GitHub?

Tags: github, branch

How to apply the rules on the base branch and then inherit those rules to other branches created from that base branch in GitHub?

Let's say I have the main branch as the base branch, and then I apply some rules to the main branch. Now if I create other branches (main-1, main-2) from that base branch main, is there a way to automatically apply the base branch (main) rules to the child branches (main-1,main-2)?

This would avoid recreating the rules for each different child branch.

Thanks.